# How to write this mysql query based on laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

i want to convert the following query that supports laravel query builder

```
select specialization_master.sm_specializationtype from 
specialization_master 
join hospital_profile_master on FIND_IN_SET(specialization_master.sm_id ,  (select hospital_profile_master.hp_specialization from hospital_profile_master where hp_hospitalid = 'HOS10011'))
group by specialization_master.sm_specializationtype
```

I wrote this as below

```
$query_filter_dept_list = DB::table('specialization_master')
                            ->join('hospital_profile_master',DB::raw(FIND_IN_SET(specialization_master.sm_id , (select hospital_profile_master.hp_specialization from hospital_profile_master where hp_hospitalid = $hospital_id))))
                            ->select('specialization_master.sm_specializationtype')
                            ->groupBy('specialization_master.sm_specializationtype')
                            ->get();
```

but it showing error ***FatalErrorException in ReceptionistController.php line 35: syntax error, unexpected 'hospital_profile_master' (T_STRING)***

Comment: You need to update your `DB::raw()` to wrap the query in `'` or `"`. So, `DB::raw('FIND_IN_SET...')`, instead of `DB::raw(FIND_IN_SET...)`.

Comment: Wouldnt it be more easy without query builder and just use \DB:select(); approach?

Comment: @KirkBeard yes i already tried using '' but it's not working but even not showing error either

Comment: finally i used /DB::select() approach which is solved my problem and thanks to @DavidLavieri ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes finally i used /DB::select(); approach to solve the issue and its working fine.